# Touch count Android with changed icon/image

Tags: android, count, touch

I want to make app that can count touch event on Android by changed image/icon that I touched.
The app would be like this:

1. App runs and shows an image 1
2. I touch the image 1 and it turns to image 2
3. When I release my finger, it turns to image 1 again
4. And counting by how many image 2 shows up

I'm very new to Android Java programming, and if there is an example project, it would help me so much.

Thanks for help :) *sorry for my English

Comment: i have tried to changed image from image 1 to image 2, but i can't make the code for counting it , it is use looping or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set on touch listener for your imageView:

```
public class MainAcivity extends Activity {
ImageView img;
TextView mText;
int counter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            counter=0;
            mText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);      
            myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                                    myImageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
                            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                                    myImageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image2);
                                    counter++;
                                    mText.setText("Count: "+counter);
                            }
                            return false;
                    }
            });
    }
    ...
}
```

MotionEvent.ACTION_UP signifies a release event, whereas MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN signifies touch event.

counter stores the no.of times image 2 was shown, initialize counter to 0 in onCreate() method

Comment: thanks gkapagunta :), i still stuck in a how to counting that ?

Comment: declare an integer variable counter as a global variable for your activity and just before setting your ontouch listener in the oncreate method, set counter=0.on every touch, counter increments as i specified in the code, and at anytime if u want to know how many times the image was shown, just check the value of counter :)

Comment: and don't forget to mark the answer as correct if u find this as the correct answer :)

Comment: can you guide me to a right code ? :)
int counter = 0;
counter++;
and how to implement to code ?
counter++;
textView1.setText(counter++); 

im still confused .:)

Comment: well, what do you want to do with the count value? display it in a textview?

Comment: yap , i want to display the count to textview :)

Comment: i edited my answer.it shows the updated counter on a textview.